# Normalize a value along a circle's radius

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I am trying to implement the dragging / progress effect as seen on cs.kenji-special.info

Basically, I am outputting a N number of divs into the page and move them horizontally. I want to track how much progress you have made scrolling and show it on the circle behind. I am imagining I should track the distance between viewPort's center and the first item's X position..

I have the total elements' width, but after countless iterations I still can't achieve the effect...

[image]

Any help is more then appreciated.

Comment: You can simplify the problem by making the progress indicator a circular graphic that you can rotate. The amount of rotation of the loading circle (in percent) is equal to the amount of horizontal scrolling (in percent) that you have done with the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if I got completely your question, but you can have a point on a circle representing a value by taking the value range and normalize trought 2*PI radiants, ie ( in sort of pseudocode ):

```
dv = 2PI/(Max-Min);
currantAngle = (currentValue-Min)*dv;
currentPointX = centerX+radius*cos(currentAngle)
currentPointY = centerY+radius*sin(currentAngle)
```

if your value is zero based it's even simpler:

```
dv = 2PI/(Max);
currantAngle = (currentValue)*dv;
currentPointX = centerX+radius*cos(currentAngle)
currentPointY = centerY+radius*sin(currentAngle)
```

With this code point start from first quadrant and move counterclockwise, you can play by offsetting the angle and changing signs to move in opposite directions, but I think this let's you start.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! Thats precisely the formula I needed - should work on my trigonometry skills. Thanks!